# Want to print out a list of items from another view django

Tags: django, templates, list, view

I have a view which displays a list items.

```
def edit_order(request, order_no):

try:
    status_list = models.Status.objects.all()
    order = models.Order.objects.get(pk = order_no)
    if order.is_storage:
        items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(orderstoragelist__order__pk = order.pk)
    else:
        items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(orderservicelist__order__pk = order.pk)
except:
    return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

I want to put these list of item in another view. Unfortunately this is proving to be trickier then I thought.

```
@login_required
def client_items(request, client_id = 0):
    client = None
    items = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        items = client.storageitem_set.all()
        item_list = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(orderstoragelist__order__pk = order.pk)
    except:
        return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
    return render_to_response('items.html', {'items':items, 'client':client, 'item_list':item_list}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I thought maybe I can just paste the definition of items and just call that item_list but that does not work. Any ideas

items.html

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{item.tiptop_id}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do here. status_list is defined but not used in your first example. Is it relevant? You might be better off adding a Manager method, that's the usual way of adding model-wide behaviour to a model...

Comment: I have a list of items on one view called edit_order. I would like to display the SAME list of items in the client_item view. That is all.

Comment: Hi, are you getting an error when trying to render item_list on your template or something like that?

Comment: I get a white screen with the url printed on the screen. /tiptop/client in this case.

Comment: In that case, can we see your template too?

Comment: @Federico ok I will upload it: Updated

Comment: Except for the missing } in, the template seems ok. First of all, are you sure item_list has results? I see you're using `order.pk` in your query, but order is nowhere to be found. Can you count the objects returned in your queryset? a `print len(item_list)` before the `except` line will do.

Comment: @Fedrico I will do this tomorrow. I will update about 10am GMT

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I get a white screen with the url printed on the screen. /tiptop/client in this case.

Because that's what you've asked for:

```
except:
    return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
```

This means that if there are any bugs or problems in the above, your view will simply output a response containing just that URL. Maybe you meant to use `HttpResponseRedirect`, so the browser actually redirects to the URL - but still you should not use a blank `except`, as it prevents you from seeing what is actually going wrong.

To answer the main question, think about what your `edit_order` view returns: it gives you a complete HTML response with a rendered template. How could you use that as an element in a query in another view? You need to think logically about this.

One possible solution would be to define a separate function which just returns the *data* you want - as a plain queryset - and both views can call it. Does that do what you want?

Comment: I guess this would be the solution, if I new how to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you any further. If you don't know how to define a function and return data from it, then you shouldn't be asking questions on StackOverflow, you should be following a basic "introduction to programming" tutorial.