# Django want to use a variable from another view

Tags: django, templates, variables, view

I have a list of items in a view called client_items. I want to be able to use the variable items_list`which is another view called edit_order in client_items. So is there a way to call the variable from a different view? (Import a variable from another view and be able to use this variable in the other) I cannot just write it in client_items view because it needs an order_no augment.

Edit: here is my latest views. I have tried creating another views called items_in_edit_order. At this point I get `order_no not defined.

```
    def items_in_edit_order(order_no):
        order = models.Order.objects.get(pk = order_no)
        return order

def client_items(request, client_id = 0):
    client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
    items = client.storageitem_set.all()
    order = items_in_edit_order(order_no)
    return render_to_response('items.html', {'items':items, 'client':client, 'order':order}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want to print out a list of items from another view django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935019/want-to-print-out-a-list-of-items-from-another-view-django)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just adding, since no one has said this and it seems like you don't understand this yet:

Your `client_items` view must, somehow, have access to the `order_no` variable. If for some reason the value is not being passed along via the URL, it must get the value from somehwere. There are only three real locations where it could get this value:

1. **Database**: this will work if you are, for example, storing something like a cart which is directly linked to a user. So for example, you might be able to do something like `order_no = Order.objects.filter(cart__user=request.user).order_no` which would get the order associated with the user's current cart, then return the `order_no` value.
2. **Session**: you store the order_no in the session. This would assume you had an earlier view where the value for `order_no` was set, at which point you would save it using `request.session['order_no']=order_no`. Later, when you wanted to retrieve the value, you would simply use `order_no=request.session['order_no']` in the view.
3. **Cookie**: not really recommended, but an option nonetheless. It's complicated because in the first view you'd have to create the response object (as in `resp = render_to_response(template_name, locals(), RequestContext(request))` and *then* write a cookie to it `resp.set_cookie("order_no", order_no)`. You retrieve it using `request.COOKIES['order_no']`

There are other, bizarre, places you could store the value: files, cache, other data storage formats, etc. Not at all recommended.

Comment: @Jordan- Using Sessions it the best way to do this. some good information, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No. Write a function that returns the value you're interested in, and call it from both views.

Answer (score 0):

What the guy said above is correct. You shouldn't attempt to "share" variables to different views.

However in the event you must or have a reason to then you could just store it in the session and then you have access to it in any view that has access to the "request".

Hope that helps.